# Анимация заканчивается рывком, как сделать ее плавной

Tags: html, css

Анимация на css, запустите пример, чтобы увидеть. Каждые 6 секунд прерывается и начинается по новой. Как сделать, чтобы она была плавно бесконечной, подскажите? :)

```css
body {
  background-color: #000000;
}
.hero-waves {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.wave1 use {
  -webkit-animation: hero-wave1 10s linear infinite;
  animation: hero-wave1 10s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation-delay: -2s;
  animation-delay: -2s;
}

.wave2 use {
  -webkit-animation: hero-wave2 8s linear infinite;
  animation: hero-wave2 8s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation-delay: -2s;
  animation-delay: -2s;
}

.wave3 use {
  -webkit-animation: hero-wave3 6s linear infinite;
  animation: hero-wave3 6s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation-delay: -2s;
  animation-delay: -2s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes hero-wave1 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(85px, 0%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-90px, 0%);
  }
}

@keyframes hero-wave1 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(85px, 0%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-90px, 0%);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes hero-wave2 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-90px, 0%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(85px, 0%);
  }
}

@keyframes hero-wave2 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-90px, 0%);
  }
  100% {с
    transform: translate(85px, 0%);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes hero-wave3 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-90px, 0%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(85px, 0%);
  }
}

@keyframes hero-wave3 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-90px, 0%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(85px, 0%);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg class="hero-waves" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 24 150 28 " preserveAspectRatio="none">
      <defs>
        <path id="wave-path" d="M-160 44c30 0 58-18 88-18s 58 18 88 18 58-18 88-18 58 18 88 18 v44h-352z">
      </defs>
      <g class="wave1">
        <use xlink:href="#wave-path" x="50" y="3" fill="rgba(255,255,255, .1)">
      </g>
      <g class="wave2">
        <use xlink:href="#wave-path" x="50" y="0" fill="rgba(255,255,255, .2)">
      </g>
      <g class="wave3">
        <use xlink:href="#wave-path" x="50" y="9" fill="#fff">
      </g>
    </svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас опечатка в коде

```
@keyframes hero-wave2 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-90px, 0%);
  }
  100% {с
    transform: translate(85px, 0%);
  }
}
```

Символ `с` оказался не в том месте :)

Comment: Спасибо огромное, как я не увидел, 100 раз перечитывая :D

Comment: А разве подсветки синтаксиса нет в Вашем редакторе?